# problems with reading of text file in java

Tags: java, csv, filereader

I use a FileWriter to save a CSV file (text file).
All seems good when I read it with a text editor like sublime text.
But when I read it with java I get some nasty characters, anyhow I try to read it.

An example of the reading:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String ligne;

            BufferedReader fichier1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nom_office));
            while ((ligne = fichier1.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(ligne);
            }
            fichier1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //String totalité = new String(encoded, encoding);
        String totalité = sb.toString();
```

the result of these following statements is:

```
System.out.println("##############");
System.out.println(totalité);
```

> PK    ! T��ep    [Content_Types].xml �(� 
>   �TKn�0�W�"o���EUU�,[$�L/�i"m�k�IO)�

...and so on.
why isn't it the same result as in sublime text?

Comment: You have to use proper encoding while reading the file `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(<file>), <encoding>));`

Comment: You don't seem to read the actual CSV file that you wrote, but something else. Print the absolute path of the file when writing it. Print the absolute path of the file when reading it.

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem, i.e. the text file is NOT simple ASCII text but UTF-8 or something else. Sublime presumably detects the actual encoding and handles it accordingly.  Can you post the writing code as I suspect it is outputting the text with character encoding that the reader also needs to support.

Comment: It looks like you trying to read some Exell file.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read some HTTP download in its entirely without stripping the headers, observing content-encoding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` uses default system encoding which probably isn't `UTF-8` and that's what you need here. Try this:
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));`
Also, your IDEs console needs to be configured to use UTF-8, that's really important!